# Is there a way to make background color stretch alongwith the content on h2?

Tags: css

I have following set in the css for the h2 element:

```
...
    width: 10%;
    display: block;
    background-color: #eee;


    overflow-x: visible;
    white-space: nowrap;
...
```

If I have an h2 header with text that cannot fit on one line (on the right-most column) this helps me push the text over to the side.  I want the full width of the text to have the background color, and hence the "display: block;" rule. But this does not work. Only the width (10%) is colored.

Any suggestions?
Thx,
Tabrez

[image]

Here is an example with sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/VZccE/18

The chosen solution: Got rid of the width from h2 per suggestion from ptriek.  I had it sitting there by mistake.  It needed to be a couple of levels higher.

Comment: just remove the width? i don't really understand why you set width to 10%?

Comment: I have a 3rd column next to it.  I am ok with a few headers spilling on to the third column but I don't want the whole column to expand beyond 10%.

Comment: I put sample code for it too. Please check it out.

Comment: ptriek: Turns out that I was setting the width at the wrong location.  You are correct. I don't need the width on h2.  I removed it and it works! Thanks! If you put this as an answer I will go ahead and accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the width? I don't really understand why you set width to 10%?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question as "I want the header to wrap at width 10%, but still have a background for the entire width (100%)."

If that's what you mean, you can wrap the header in a `div`.  If you apply the background to the `div`, you can set the header width do whatever you like.

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LjpuM/)

Comment: Actually, I have 3 divs.  First is 70%, second 10% and the last column (unimportant one) is 10%.  I want these three divs to be top-aligned, but if the headers in column 2 are wider than 10%, I want to allow them to stretch over column 3.  The text does stretches without any issues once I put overflow-x:visible.  But only 10% width of that text has the background-color.  So, the text that is stretched over column 3 (which has lower z-index) does not have the background color as I want.

Comment: I have added a screenshot to show what is happening. I hope that will help.

Comment: Could you give an example I can test with?  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) is a good site to use.  Just put the smallest amount of code that demonstrates the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: FakeRainBrigand - thanks for the reply.  Look at the first header in column 2 in the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/VZccE/

Comment: I just got rid of width as suggested by ptriek and it worked.  I was setting it at the wrong level.  Sorry for the trouble and thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the header to break out of the enclosing `div` by using absolute positioning.  Here's an example:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <h2 id="hello">Hello World! I like cookies!</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 50px; height: 100px;
    background: #f00;
    position: relative;
}

h2 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #00f;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0;
}
```

These background colors are just so you can see how the elements are positioned.  You still need to specify `white-space: nowrap` to force the header into one line, but the special sauce that makes this work is the positioning.  Notice how the enclosing element has `position: relative` - this ensures that the absolutely positioned `h2` has its position based on the `div`, not the window.

See this in action: http://jsbin.com/aganam/3

Comment: that looks promising!  The end result is exactly what I am looking for.  So, would I right something to automatically encompass the h2 values withing div?  I will try that if nobody else comes up with a solution that does not require an extra div around the element.  Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: I just noticed one issue.  It seems you have specified a width for the div.  That will not work for my case unless I use javascript to manipulate it based on the text header width.  Otherwise, I will get the 50x100 px blue box even if say the text is 40 px wide. Is that true or am I missing something?

Comment: @Tabrez - The width of the enclosing `div` is meaningless - I simply made it smaller than the `h2` to illustrate that the technique works.  The div itself doesn't affect the header at all, and in fact could be any element you want.

Comment: @Tabrez - the key is that whatever element contains the `h2` needs to have `position:relative` specified, or else the header can't break out of the containing element's box.

Comment: I just got rid of width as suggested by ptriek and it worked.  I was setting it at the wrong level.  Sorry for the trouble and thanks for your suggestions.